# How do you say "pesto" in Esperanto, referring to the sauce?

Tags: single-word-requests

According to [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#pesto) and all other dictionaries I used, *pesto* is an infectious disease, rather than an tasty Italian dish. On the other hand, there is a [Wikipedia article](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesto_(kondimento)), which doesn't provide any convincing arguments for this spelling. *Peŝto* is probably not an option, because it is already used for a [city name](https://eo.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pe%C5%9Dto).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[John Well’s dictionary](https://www.smashwords.com/books/view/508176) has the following:

> **pesto** pist-ita saŭco, -aĵo

So I guess you can say *pistita saŭco* or just *pistaĵo* for short.

Apparently the Italian word *pesto* is derived from the Latin word *pistus*, so presumably they have the same etymology. I guess *pistita* is a literal translation of the Italian word.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware about a single Esperanto word for *pesto*. Personally I use to call it *bazilia pistitaĵo [laŭ Ĝenova maniero]*, which is a kind of a calque of the italian *pesto alla Genovese* (*pestle-crushed [sauce] in the style of Genoa*).

Anyway I won't be shocked to see *pest/o* enter the dictionaries in the future, as it is the obvious solution according to the 15-th rule. Homographs are rare in Esperanto, but we already have some (e.g. [koreo](http://vortaro.net/#koreo)).
A way to avoid that could be *pesto/o*, like happened with [*polo/o*](http://vortaro.net/#poloo), but I've never heard anyone using this form.

Comment: Another possibility is to introduce an all-in-one definition and let people make their own choice.
_**Pesto:** italdevena saŭco, kiu mezepoke mortigis milionojn da homoj_. :p

Answer (score 1):

La Esperanta Vikipedio de multaj jaroj nomas tion "pesto", kaj mi de multaj jaroj uzas ĝin en Esperanto, ĉefe en nia familia uzado de Esperanto. Parolante kun iu, kiu eble ne konas la vorton "pesto" en tiu signifo, aŭ en la maloftega okazo, ke vere povus esti konfuzo kun la malsano, oni kompreneble ankaŭ povas diri "bazilia saŭco", "pistita saŭco", "bazilia pistita saŭco" aŭ "saŭco el pistita bazilio" depende de la precizemo.